# apt package manager constant problems with sources

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dpkg

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed, and I am having constant problems with the package manager. Currently the issue is I am trying to install docker and it constantly fails because it cannot install the required packages. When I do
`apt update` I get the following errors:

`https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.`

`E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`

I have tried reinstallng ca-certificates to no avail.

I have had similar issues with the package manager in the past, for example when I tried to do a system update it gave me an error message that the package manager is broken, which was fixed by running

`sudo apt install -f`

It seems to me something is wrong with how the package manager is set up. What would the course of action be to reset/reinstall the package manager correctly? If this is not possible how would I go about identifying where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I read the following at https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/:

> Prerequisites
>
> To install Docker Desktop successfully, you must:
>
> - Meet the system requirements
> - Have a 64-bit version of either Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish 22.04 (LTS) or Ubuntu Impish Indri 21.10. Docker Desktop is supported on
>   x86_64 (or amd64) architecture. ...

Note that 20.04 is not mentioned, so I doubt it has anything to do with apt.

Comment: Thank you, I updated Ubuntu to 22.04, but I am still getting constant errors with apt. When trying to install docker I get`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of docker-desktop:
 docker-desktop depends on qemu-system-x86 (>= 5.2.0); however:
  Package qemu-system-x86 is not installed.` .